# During change event radio button affects wrong form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a page with multiple forms and a change listener on each a couple of radio buttons to submit the form on change. Except, it's submitting the wrong form. I went through the source code on the page and didn't find any unmatched tags (maybe someone knows a good html linter just in case?).

This is the most relevant JS I have:

```
  var AcceptanceBtns = this.AcceptanceBtns = function (accBtnForm) {
    this.acceptanceBtnForm = accBtnForm;

    this.labels = this.acceptanceBtnForm.find("label.approval-buttons");

    this.radios = this.labels.find("input.radio-btn");

    this.checkedRadio = this.radios.filter(':checked');
    this.styleCheckedBtn();
  }

  AcceptanceBtns.prototype.confirmBtns = function () {
    var that = this;
    this.styleAcceptBtn()
    this.radios.on("change", function() {
      console.log("going");
      var radio = $(this);
      var label = radio.parent();
      that.styleBtnsOnChange(label)
      that.radios.off();
      that.acceptanceBtnForm.submit();
    });
  };

  AcceptanceBtns.prototype.startListening = function () {
    if (this.acceptanceBtnForm.length === 0) { return; }
    this.confirmBtns();
    this.submitResponse();
  };

  var AcceptAffiliateBtns = this.AcceptAffiliateBtns = function (formEl) {
    AB.call(this, formEl);
  };

  AcceptAffiliateBtns.prototype = Object.create(AB.prototype);

  AcceptAffiliateBtns.prototype.constructor = AcceptAffiliateBtns;

$(document).on("page:change", function () {
  if (typeof aab === 'undefined') {
    var aab = {};
  } else {
    $.each(aab, function (key, val) { val.stopListening(); });
  }
  $('form.accepting-affiliates').each(function (i, el) {
    aab[i.toString()] = new AcceptAffiliateBtns ($(el));
    aab[i.toString()].startListening();
  });
});
```

When debugging I checked in the console and `that` in the `on change` event refers to the first form, although `this` outside of the on change scope is correct (and there's some js styling as you can see and it works fine for all buttons). So either the radio btn is changing the first form, or the variables are getting confused between instances

Comment: I only see you using `that` in `confirmBtns` and I don't see how `confirmBtns` relates to the `change` event.

Comment: `confirmBtns` is called in `startListening` which I didn't include to avoid clutter and because everything is called ok.

Comment: How `confirmBtns` is called determines the value of `this` so that's pretty important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had had this problem a couple of years ago, so I went back to that project to see what I did. It's a hard problem to Google so I'll answer it myself for future searchers.

The JS was not a problem, it has to do with labels and radio buttons (not sure about other tags in forms). If you're clicking the label, even if the radio button is nested within it it seems that the label will check its `for` attribute, and then find the first radio button with the matching `id`. Since the radio buttons are all the same it changes the radio button in the first form. So you just need to make sure each label and radio has unique `for`/ `id`'s.

```
// var x = randomNumber(); 
<label for="aab_" + x>
  <input id="aab_" + x selected="selected" type="radio" value="true" checked="checked" name="foo[bar]" />Accept
</label>

// var y = randomNumber();     
<label for="aab_" + y>
  <input id="aab_" + y selected="selected" type="radio" value="false" name="foo[bar]" />Reject
</label>

Rails solution:
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:bar, [[true, 'Accept'],[false, 'Reject']],
:first, :last, { selected: true }) do |b| %>
  <%= b.label(for: "aab_#{b.object_id}") {
    b.radio_button(id: "aab_#{b.object_id}") + b.text } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Renaming `var that = this` is not a cure. Your `that` must be evaluated to an existing element **at the moment it is used**. In any ind of `loop` your `that` means the last `this` used. The known cure is to wrap `this` or `that` into a closure.

Comment: Actually, `that` was used fine, as was my code. As I put in my answer it was a gotcha relating to how labels find the radio buttons they're affecting.

Comment: "that was used fine, as was my code". You said I trust. So What Is The Problem?  Except `that` is not always `what` you think?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the label tag with the same id for multiple elements:

```
// var x = randomNumber(); 
<label for="aab_" + x>
  <input id="aab_" + x selected="selected" type="radio" value="true" checked="checked" name="foo[bar]" />Accept
</label>

// var y = randomNumber();     
<label for="aab_" + y>
  <input id="aab_" + y selected="selected" type="radio" value="false" name="foo[bar]" />Reject
</label>
```

The solution is not to use the label tag because label it needs a unique id.